# "antes que" vs. "antes de que"

Tags: definiciones, gramática, adverbios

What is the difference between the phrases *antes que* and *antes de que*? When should each be used? Are there contexts where one is correct and one is incorrect, or are they completely synonymous?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The DPD has the answer: [antes que o antes de que](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/1412/antes-que-vs-antes-de-que). Here's the relevant portion:

> 3 . *antes que* o *antes de que*. Con significado temporal, ambas construcciones son válidas. En un principio, precediendo a la oración
>   que expresa el acontecimiento que se toma como referencia, se usó solo
>   la locución conjuntiva *antes que* (en latín, *ante quam*, *antequam*):
>   «Antes que ellas se levanten, pasemos delante dellas» (MtzToledo
>   Corbacho [Esp. 1438]). Cuando el término de referencia temporal es un
>   sustantivo, un pronombre o un infinitivo, *antes* debe ir seguido de la
>   preposición *de*: «Antes d’estos quinze días [...] / Aquellos atamores a
>   vos los pondrán delant» (Cid [Esp. c1140]); «Antes de llegar se
>   detuvieron en una posada a tomar un trago» (UPietri Oficio [Ven.
>   1976]). Del cruce de *antes que* y *antes de*, surgió *antes de que*,
>   variante de la locución conjuntiva que algunos gramáticos censuraron
>   en un principio por dequeísta (→ dequeísmo), pero que hoy se acepta
>   como válida. Así, es igualmente correcto decir *Llegará antes que
>   anochezca* y *Llegará antes de que anochezca*. Cuando la locución expresa
>   preferencia, solo es válida la forma *antes que*: «Antes que verlo
>   detrás de una reja [...], prefiero verlo muerto» (Asenjo Días [Esp.
>   1982]); con este último sentido, es posible la intercalación de
>   elementos entre *antes* y *que*: *Antes muerto que vencido*.

To summarize:

Both expressions are valid when their meaning is that of a temporary locution:

> *Llegará antes que anochezca* y *Llegará antes de que anochezca*.

Only *antes que* is a valid expression when the intended meaning is that of preference:

> *Antes que verlo detrás de una reja, prefiero verlo muerto*. but **not** *Antes de que verlo detrás de una reja, prefiero verlo muerto*.

Comment: Thanks! Could you briefly summarize in English for those that can't understand the DPD?

Comment: @jrdioko I was just doing that ;-) By the way, do you know how can I put some text in a different color (red, for example)?

Comment: Not that I know of (and that's probably by design). **Bolding** things makes them stand out though.

Comment: @jrdioko: but bold-facing might be considered in a "positive" way; I, on the other hand, want to stress the fact that some sentence must not be used.

Comment: See [this meta question](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/122/indicating-wrong-sentences).

Comment: @jrdioko: yes, I've already read the question; in this particular case, however, I really would like to use the standard "red color mark" to signal an incorrection... perhaps I'll revisit that question.

Comment: This is very enlightening. I (native speaker) was actually convinced that _antes que_ plus verb phrase was a horrible mistake, even though everybody speaks like that.