# "después que" vs. "después de que"

Tags: definiciones, gramática, adverbios

Along the lines of [another question I asked](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/1412/antes-que-vs-antes-de-que), what is the difference between *después que* and *después de que*? Is the situation the same as for *antes*? When are they synonymous, and when is one correct and the other incorrect?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, according to DPD's entry [después que o después de que](http://buscon.rae.es/dpdI/SrvltGUIBusDPD?lema=despu%E9s), the answer is similar:

> 1. *después que* o *después de que*. Con significado temporal, ambas construcciones son válidas. En un principio, precediendo a la oración que expresa el acontecimiento que se toma como referencia, se usó solo la locución conjuntiva *después que* (en latín, *post quam*, *postquam*): «E después que esto ovo fecho, dixo que se quería tornar para su tierra» (Sendebar [Esp. 1253]). Cuando el término de referencia temporal no es una oración con verbo en forma personal, sino un sustantivo, un pronombre o un infinitivo, ha de usarse el adverbio *después* seguido de la preposición *de*: «Estábamos todos sentados en el corredor tomando el sol después de comer» (González Dios [Méx. 1999]). Del cruce de *después que* y *después de* surgió *después de que*, variante de la locución conjuntiva que algunos gramáticos censuraron en un principio por dequeísta (→  dequeísmo), pero que hoy se considera válida. Así, es igualmente correcto decir *Después que te fuiste, llamó tu hermano* y *Después de que te fuiste, llamó tu hermano*.

Answer (score 1):

"*Después que*" and "*después de que*" are the same thing. Both are correct, but "*después de que*" is more a word by word translation (from English) and maybe it doesn't sound so good.

Both of them mean that the next action is a subordinated one.

For example:

> El avión llegará **después que** amanezca. (The aircraft will arrive after dawn)
>
> El avión llegará **después de que** amanezca. (The aircraft will arrive after dawn).

For *antes* it is more or less the same thing but, in expressions about one's preferences, we use *antes que*.

For example:

> Antes que coger una moto, prefiero esperar. (Rather than riding a motorbike, I prefer to wait).
> Antes de que llegue mi padre, limpiaré la mesa (Before my father arrives, I'll clean the table)

Answer (score 0):

According to RAE in its entry to [después](http://dle.rae.es/?id=DQBHjWr), you can only use "después que" when referring to "desde". Otherwise, it's always "después de que". If not it's what we call a "queísmo".

Comment: I don't agree. See the other answers.

Comment: That use is marked as archaic (*Era u* = *Era usado*) in the dictionary.