# Después de que + subjuntivo imperfecto en la lengua escrita

Tags: subjuntivo

Mi libro de gramática española dice que en la lengua escrita es normal usar el subjuntivo imperfecto después de la conjunción *después de que*, aunque la acción de la oración subordinada expresa un hecho acaecido. Estaba buscando un ejemplo para ilustrar lo dicho arriba y encontré esta frase:

*Las fuerzas de seguridad "están pendientes" **después de que el Estado Islámico mencionara a Toledo en un vídeo**.*

(http://www.eldigitalcastillalamancha.es/la-policia-esta-pendiente-despues-de-que-el-estado-islamico-mencionara-a-toledo-en-un-video-207196.htm)

Me podríais decir por favor si lo que pienso es correcto o no. La ciudad española ya ha sido mencionada, entonces la acción representa un hecho realizado ¿verdad? ¿Sería posible utilizar el indefinido?

*Las fuerzas de seguridad "están pendientes" después de que el Estado Islámico **mencionó** a Toledo en un vídeo.*

Comment: Esto se debe al uso de ***de que*** en vez solo usar ***que**.* Para usar el pretérito perfecto, debemos tener *después que el Estado Islámico mencionó* (...).

Comment: Uy yo no sabía que hay diferencia en el uso entre „después de que“ y „después que“... Gracias

Comment: Yo no creo que haya ninguna diferencia entre añadir la preposición *de* o no. [Aquí](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/1417/despu%C3%A9s-que-vs-despu%C3%A9s-de-que) hay una pregunta al respecto que te puede interesar.